# using fprintf to print a float with a user specified precision

Tags: matlab, printf, precision

I have a script in matlab that takes inputs from the user, computes some value and prints it on the screen. The script is quite complex and I would like to be able to give the user the option to display the numbers to whatever precision they wish. The following code seems to work fine, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this than going to each print statement and change it to `.*f` and adding the precision at the end of it. Is there something I can put at the beginning of my script that will override every print statement and force it to write to a specified precision without having to modify each statement? Here is the code that currently works:

```matlab
num = 1.123456789;
precision = 3 %defined by user
fprintf('%.*f',precision,num);
```

I'd like to avoid going to each `fprintf` statement and change the `%.16f` to `%.*f` and then have to add the precision variable at the end preceding the value. My code has over 50000 lines of code with a lot of them being print statements with multiple float values, adding the `precision` variable right in front of each `%f` will reduce readability and take a long time. Using the replace all built in matlab won't also add the precision variable at the correct position so that's out of the question. Is there something similar to format long for scripts that automatically prints everything in the script at a specified precision?

Comment: You’ve got 50000 lines of code with `fprintf` statements scattered all around it and you are worried about impacting readability??? That ship has sailed a long time ago ...

Comment: Anyway, I think replacing `fprintf` with a custom function is the only way you’ll avoid your issue. But I think it’s a non-issue.

Comment: well I took great care to make it readable. The script is made up of over 500 functions with around 100 lines each, all commented and for each function, there are user prompts for input and fprintfs for outputs. The issue is not just readability but also fixing the entire thing.

Comment: Sorry, you said you had “a script” and then you said 50000 lines of code, so I assumed the worst. :)

Comment: It’s good practice to separate computation and output, something to think about next time you start a program like this. Put input in one function, and output in one function.

Comment: Do you use `%.16f` everywhere you print? It might be possible to change all `fprintf` calls to a custom function, which replaces the 16 with an asterisk, and calls `fprintf` with the right values. Use a global variable (modified only once at the beginning of the program) for precision.

Comment: yeah I do use .16f everywhere. How would I do this? I'll also keep in mind what you said about separating ouputs in the future.

Comment: @SamuelSnerden Give regular expressions a try. On Windows, an editor that allows for that somewhat easily is Notepad++ (press ctrl+H to open replace menu, select 'regular expression'). Since your familiar with MATLAB, the help page / function you can look out for there is 'regexprep'.